# Convert Struct type to vect int

Tags: c++, data-structures, type-conversion

I have problem i need to convert from my "Array" structure to `std::vector<int>`... the point is i have a dynamic matrix who purpose is being Database. But at some point i need to move some values from the 'Array' to a vector. and i get the fallowing error

```
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits  /stl_iterator_base_types.h:166:53: error: 'int' is not a class, struct, or union type
```

Anyone has some clue how to achive this thing?

structure:

```
const int days=31;
const int exp=6;

struct Arr{
    int days;
    int exp;
    int **M;
};
typedef Arr* Array;
```

vector:

```
 vector <int> vec(31);
```

EDIT:

```
int dayExp(int day, Array &M){
    int s=0;
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        s += M->M[day][i];
    }
    return s;
}

void srtDesc(Array &M){
    vector <int> vec(31);
    for(int i=0;i<31;i++){
        vec[i]=dayExp(i, M);
    }
    sort(vec[0],vec[1]);

    for(int i=0;i<31;i++){
        cout<< vec[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message suggests that you do something like vec[0].days or so, which cannot work because vec holds ints. Show us the code you are using to access and convert your struct and maybe someone will be able to help.

Comment: Could you be more specific what you want to do? Do you want to know how to declare a vector? Or are you interested in transferring values from a C style array to a vector?

Comment: added, the way i tought it should work

Comment: @Jaywalker i try to move a specific sum of elemnts from my  Array  struct (c++) to a vector.h type

Comment: The problem is with the line where you call `sort` inside `srtDesc`. What does this line do? For sorting you need to provide iterators and not elements of the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Arr` struct does not implicitly convert to `int`.  First of all, your struct contains 3 `int` types, whereas a `vector<int>`  is one `int` at a time.

If you want to put your `Arr` into a `vector`,  you should create a `std::vector<Arr>` and then call `push_back` on it to put your `Arr` structs in it.

```
std::vector<Arr> myvec;

myvec.push_back(someArr);
```

You will need to create `for` loop that goes through the length - 1 of your array and calls `push_back` to put each item in the `vector`

Comment: i added the code were i attempt to add some of my int to the vec.. considering i refer to one int shoulden't it work?
btw i`m not familiar with push_back concept... can you explain/link it to me